# really confused on how to concatenate two arrays contained in two different Array

Tags: javascript

So I have two similar Array`state.camData` and `data.camData` that contain some data, one of which is an Array of Events.

I would like to keep `data.camData` but also concat it Events with `state.camData` Events.

here is just return a concatenated list of Events only. I lose the other elements inside camData such as ID. I am not sure how I can keep those and update just the Events.

```
camData.Events.length //100
state.camData.Events.length //100
```

```
let camEvents = data.camData.map((camData) => {
  return camData?.Events.concat(state?.camData[camData.CamID]?.Events)  
});
```

console.log(camEvents[0].length); //200

since I was not able to keep the original value on the map, I am now reassigning camEvents
to the data.camData

```
for (let i = 0; i < camEvents.length; i++) {
  data.camData[i].Events = camEvents[i].Events;
}
```

However, I don't understand why the number is still 100 and not 200 as camEvents[0].length

```
console.log("data.camData", data.camData[0].Events.length); //100
```

The Arrays look like this

```
[
{CamId: 1, LastStatus: 'ONLINE', Events: Array(100)}
{CamId: 2, LastStatus: 'ONLINE', Events: Array(100)}
{CamId: 3, LastStatus: 'ONLINE', Events: Array(100)}
{CamId: 4, LastStatus: 'ONLINE', Events: Array(100)}
{CamId: 5, LastStatus: 'ONLINE', Events: Array(100)}
{CamId: 6, LastStatus: 'ONLINE', Events: Array(100)}
{CamId: 7, LastStatus: 'ONLINE', Events: Array(100)}
{CamId: 8, LastStatus: 'ONLINE', Events: Array(100)}
]
```

Comment: Could you knock up a demo showing the issue, there is really not enough detail here to help, as what is `removeDuplicatesFromArray` and `SensorID` , is `SensorID` really just an array index. etc..  ps.  concatenating arrays, really is as simple as doing `[...arr1, ...arr2]`

Comment: why wouldn't you simply do: `data.camData.Events.concat(state.camData.Events); `?

Comment: The the expected value of 200 is when they are merged `Array(100)` + `Array(100)`?